# New to Expression and have problems updating navagation bar

Tags: templates, structure, navigation, links

Site was out sourced and getting no response from developer.

I need to add a new link to one of the navigation bars. 
There are 2 top navigation bars on my site.

Main home page code:

```
{html-open}
{html-head-open}
{exp:low_variables:single var="meta"}
{exp:low_variables:single var="favicon"}
{exp:low_variables:single var="css"}
{exp:low_variables:single var="js"}
{embed="partial/html-head-close" is_home="true"}
{exp:stash:get name="content"}
{exp:low_variables:single var="html-close"}
```

---

code from Secondary navbar

```
<div class="navbar-secondary">
    <div class="container">
        {exp:structure:nav start_from="/" max_depth="1" css_class="list-inline list-unstyled" current_class="active" include="15|20|21"}
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I tried to add a 6 (page I need) to the Include and no go.
If I remove the any of the include numbers and view rendered template they drop off and I can add them back, but new item won't work. 
any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Thank you

John

Answer (score 1):

You need to post a page that has been assigned to use Structure. Check Structure » Settings and use one of those channels.